# Using Google Maps with Java on a Desktop Application

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, desktop-application

I want to use Google Maps on my java based application.

My application would overlay images on maps based on latitude and longitude and change position of these images with time. The time interval will be very short so it needs to be efficient.

Currently I can find following solution, but none of these works :

1) Using [Qt WebKit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qtwebkit-index.html) through [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org) : This will just open Google Maps in browser over my application, I would not have control of overlaying images on top of the Map, according to the lat/long.

2) Using [Google Maps Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/) : This would open image, but I would not be able to translate the location in lat/long into coordinates in image, also as the position of images are changing I will need zoom-in and zoom out feature, which will be unavailable here.

Is there an exiting solution which fits my need?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be less trouble to create a static website using javascript and HTML then embed it to your application.

Comment: umm, even if I do make the website, how will I overlay images on top of the map? (I have lat/long in a java variable) .

Comment: You would need a library to embed the website (like http://djproject.sourceforge.net) (a JEditorPane would probably fail to display google map stuff) which should allow you to interact from java to the webpage and vice-versa)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you're proposing in #2 is against Google's [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms); see 10.1.1.g&h in particular.